# how to modify exit notification to exit from a phonegap application using jquery mobile?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

I'm making a phonegap app using jquery mobile. I have searched and then found the syntax to exit from app using phone back button.

```html
<script>
document.addEventListener("deviceready", deviceready, false);
   function deviceready() 
{ document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false); 

   function onBackKeyDown() 
     { 
  if(confirm("Do you want to Exit?")) 
    { 
        navigator.app.exitApp(); 
    }
  }
    }
</script>
```

it works like the image below, but I want to modify the notification. can I change the `confirm` and `button name`? for example, change OK to A, and Cancel to B. please help me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've found this syntax and it works, but how to change the interface of the notification? How can i use css to modify it?

```html
<script>
document.addEventListener("deviceready", deviceready, false);
   function deviceready() 
{ document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false); 

   function onBackKeyDown() 
     {  
  navigator.notification.confirm(
            'Are you sure want to exit?',  // message
            onConfirm,              // callback to invoke with index of button pressed
            'confirm',            // title
            'No,Yes'          // buttonLabels
        );
  function onConfirm(buttonindex) 
    {   if(buttonindex==1) 
    { 
        navigator.app.exitApp(); 
    }
 else {
  window.close();
 }

  }
    }
}
</script>
```